# How did NASA refer to dates and times of a mission in the 1970s?

Tags: nasa, history, mission-design, deep-space, time

Back in the 1970s, how did NASA describe when an event happened during a mission?

For example, when Mariner 10 did its [fly-by of Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariner_10#Venus_flyby), how did the Mariner team refer to that moment in time?  Did they use the ordinary date and time from a particular timezone on Earth?  Did they count some number of elapsed seconds since the start of the mission?

(Apollo 11, in 1969, appeared to use elapsed days/hours/minutes/seconds from the start of the mission, at least according to [transcripts](http://www.jsc.nasa.gov/history/mission_trans/AS11_CM.PDF).)

Comment: Probably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time